# Replace values in row with column value in excel

Tags: excel, replace, find

I have what seems to be a simple find a replace question, however I am struggling to find the answer. I have thousands of rows, each contains a "Y" in some columns, this Y corresponds to value in a column B specific to each row. I need to replace "Y" with the value in column B for each row independently.

A short example: "Y" is found in E2, F2, and J2, I want to replace all Y's in row 2 with what is found in B2 (in this case "M"). There are thousands of  rows and columns, this cannot be done one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new columns for each existing column E, F, and J and use the `SUBSTITUTE` function to transform them into the what you want. For example,

```
=SUBSTITUTE(E2,"Y",B2)
```

Then paste-special as values these columns back over the originals.

If you are opposed to creating new columns to do this, this should be relatively simple using VBA.

Comment: If there really are thousands of rows *and* thousands of columns, then it will  be a large file, but I don't see why it would fundamentally be a problem otherwise.